# Can't parse full RSS from a feedburner xml

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

I'm having problems into parsing a full RSS 2.0 content feed. I have already checked all the Wordpress and Feedburner settings and it is all right.

I'm using simple_xml_load($link), PHP, but all I can get is a part of the full blog content.

Thank you all.

Comment: Specific error message? Anything? http://sscce.org/

Comment: It doesn't acctually show an error, it just don't come with the full content, the <description> just have a part of the full blog content...

Comment: What's the feed url. Are you saying the feed is only publishing part of the content?

Comment: That's the feed url http://feeds.feedburner.com/ipodschool?format=xml, when you open it in the browser you can see the full content, but, when I get it using the function simple_xml_load() there's not xml tag with the full content!

Answer (score 0):

you just have to enable "Full" option at your source (currently its configured to "Summary")